# Oauth2login in Spring Framework (non spring boot) with Azure AD/ Entra ID

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have a web app in Spring Framework with Spring Security 5.7.7 and Spring Framework 5.3.25. I am trying to implement Oauth2Login with Azure AD/ Entra ID. I have a working secret, tenant and client-id.

I am trying to setup Oauth2Login in my Spring Framework app but somehow the complete Oauth2LoginConfig is not getting triggered. When I access '/faces/start/start.jsf' it opens the page instead of redirecting me to the Azure AD login page.

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2LoginConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
        
        .oauth2Login(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
        
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(this.azureClientRegistration());
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository(
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
        return new AuthenticatedPrincipalOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository(authorizedClientService);
    }

    private ClientRegistration azureClientRegistration() {

        return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("azure")
                .clientId("my-client-id")
                .clientSecret("my-secret")
                .scope("openid", "profile", "email")
           .authorizationUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize")
                .tokenUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/token")
                .build();

}
```

}

Is there anything I am missing? Do I have to add OAuth2LoginConfig anywhere in my app to get it loaded?

My pom.xml has these dependencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding these changes fixed my issue.

1. filter and filter-mapping in my web.xml

   ```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
   ```

   ```
     <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
   ```
2. reference to my oAauth2LoginConfig class in applicationConfig-context.xml
3. content annotation config in my applicationConfig-bootstrap.xml

   <context:annotation-config />

By adding these spring started considering my Oauth2LoginConfig and started redirecting me to Azure AD/ Entra ID login page.

Answer (score 0):

ok,are u want to submit nothing to the Azure to finish OSS?
i think this is impossible
you should submit something such as  username and password and trans to Azure
then, Azure held finish the oauth and return the result to your project and decide the next business

this is my sugs

Comment: I wanted to open Azure AD/ Entra ID login page, where the user will give the username & password. I do not want to take the credentials and then pass it to Azure.